# How to install MAT in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Cannot figure out how to install MAT (memory analyzer tool) into Eclipse. Need this program to analyze heap of my Android app that is leaking.

Feel stupid, sorry ;-(

What is the steps exactly?

How should I do in Eclipse? Choose the Android SDK manager or go to help =>install new software => then enter a url string in the field (http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.1/update-site/)?

Have tried both - nothing seem to work right now.

Many thanks for a description :-)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In `Help` > `Install New Software...`, enter the following update site URL: http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.5/update-site/

(http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.1/update-site/ does not exist.)

Comment: Just FYI...a new release is available now: 
http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.5/update-site/

Comment: @thSoft: I have tried the above steps but it giving error like,           Unable to read repository at http:/mat/1.5/update-site/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http:/mat/1.5/update-site/content.xml.
URI does not specify a valid host name: http:/mat/1.5/update-site/content.xml                   could you please help me with this.

Comment: The latest released version 1.6.1 (Dec 2016) is at [link] (http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.6.1/update-site/)

Answer (score 37):

**Install Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) on Eclipse**

We need to install two eclipse plugins

1. BIRT Chart Engine *//For Getting Memory Info with Pie Chart diagrams*
2. MAT *//For Getting Memory Info*

——————————————————————————————

**Install BIRT Chart Engine plugins**

1. Eclipse —> Help Menu —> Install New Software —> Add
2. Enter below information

> Name : BIRT Chart Engine.
>
> Location: http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/4.3

Source: http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT_Update_Site_URL

Now select only Birt Chart Engine and Go for Install.

——————————————————————————————

**Install MAT plugins**

1. Eclipse —> Help Menu —> Install New Software —> Add
2. Enter below information

> Name : MAT
>
> Location: http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.5/update-site/

Source:http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php

Now select MAT and Birt Chart Plugin for MAT and Go for Install.

——————————————————————————————

**Get Heap Dump of Android Project**

Once you installed ..

1. Connect Android Device for Debugging/Testing App
2. Now Go the The project and Build/Run
3. Open DDMS —> Devices —> Select Process (Project’s Package Name in List)
4. Click the "Dump HPROF File" icon in the Devices view's toolbar (looks like a half-filled can with a downward-pointing arrow)
   [image]
5. Select the option Leak Suspects Report and click Finish.
6. That’s it!!.. You Got the Project’s Memory Heap Report

[image]

Comment: FYI, I had to check the "Contact all update sites during the install to find required software" in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to Help -> Install New Software.... Paste  http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.4/update-site/ in Work with field and press Enter. Then follow the steps you will be able to install the plugin. It's the same as other plugins installation.

The major challenge is how to use Memory Analyzer Tool. To use the Memory Analyzer Tool in Eclipse, you can follow the tutorial [Use Memory Analyzer Tool in Eclipse](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1414498909-Use-Memory-Analyzer-Tool-in-Eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

Go to HELP>INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE >ENTER NAME(MAT) AND LINK(
http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.3/update-site/)

This will work .

> The minimum Java version required to run Memory Analyzer is 1.5

Answer (score 1):

A solution to install the *latest* version of MAT, rather than the hard linked previous versions given in other answers:

Visit [this site](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php), and copy the URL next to "**Update Site:** ".

In Eclipse, go to ***Help>Install New Software*** and paste the URL you just copied.  Name it MAT, and then select the parts you want.  Follow the dialogues, restart Eclipse, and you should be good to go.

The latest version of MAT is 1.3.1, as of writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this link helped me.Its generic way just Change the version number according to you eclipse, It is a just and drag and drop approach.

http://download.eclipse.org/mat/<1.5 change it>/update-site/

if you don't want to drag and drop.

[Link: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/memory-analyzer-0](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/memory-analyzer-0)